# MDB Database with unknown characters

Tags: ms-access, character-encoding, character

I got an MDB Database with one row that displays characters like
·µ¼©µ¥¢´
instead of human readable text.

Whats wrong with that database? Any way to read the normal text? Convert it or something?

I`m thankful for every answer.

Comment: Is the whole row garbled, or is it just one (or more) text field(s) in that one row?

Comment: it`s the whole row. :(